# UV map for cuboid produces islands of same size

Tags: mesh, uv

I have a cuboid with height, width and length not of same scale. When I Smart Project UV map for this, I get islands of same size.

I think I must get islands of different sizes as height, width and length are not of same scale for my cuboid.

Am I doing anything wrong or is it normal ?

[image: UV map for cuboid]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have scaled your mesh. Unwrap operations should always be done with the object scale set to 1 (to avoid problems like yours).

In object mode if you select the object and look at the scale in the [properties region](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24526/2217), you will see that it is not all `1`.
[image: properties region with object scale highlighted]
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale*, to apply the scale.
Then in edit mode re-unwrap the mesh, and it will have the proper scale.

As an aside, if you were to use the *Unwrap* operation, blender would warn you with this message.

> Object has non-uniform scale, unwrap will operate on a non-scaled version of the mesh.